# error using custom template tags in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to use pass parameters to the URL as get request within the template. Currently I am hard coding the url such as

```
<li><a href="{{ request.path|add:'?sort_by=vehicle_price' }}" style="text-decoration: underline; color: red;">Lowest Price</a></li>
```

I found [this code](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2105/) which seems to be elegant. so I tried to use it. but it throws error:
I have correctly placed the template tag inside `myapp/templatetags/add_url_parameter.py`.

I have also registered `django.core.context_processors.request'` in `TEMPLATE_PROCESSORS`

In the template, I have:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load add_url_parameter %}
{% block content %}
<div class="sortByLinks">
      <h4>Sort by:</h4>
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li>
          {% if sort_by == "last_updated" %}

         <li> <strong>New Post</strong>
         <li><a href="{% add_get_paramater param1='vehicle_price' %}" style="text-decoration: underline; color: red;">Lowest Price</a></li>
         <li><a href="{% add_get_paramater param1='vehicle_year' %}" style="text-decoration: underline; color: red;">Latest Model Year</a></li>

          {% elif sort_by == "vehicle_price" %}
          <li><a href="{% add_get_paramater param1='last_updated' %}" style="text-decoration: underline; color: red;">New Post</a></li>
           <li> <strong>Lowest Price</strong>
           <li><a href="{% add_get_paramater param1='vehicle_year' %}" style="text-decoration: underline; color: red;">Latest Model Year</a></li>

          {% else %}
           <li><a href="{% add_get_paramater param1='last_updated' %}" style="text-decoration: underline; color: red;">New Post</a></li>
           <li><a href="{% add_get_paramater param1='vehicle_price' %}" style="text-decoration: underline; color: red;">Lowest Price</a></li>
           <li> <strong>Latest Model Year</strong>
          {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid block tag: 'add_get_paramater', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'

In template /Users/Documents/python/django/my_app/templates/my_app/blog_detail.html, error at line 127
```

and line 127 is

```
<li><a href="{% add_get_paramater param1='vehicle_price' %}" style="text-decoration: underline; color: red;">Lowest Price</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this snippet: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2105/ you probably have a typo in your template. Try changing it to `{% add_get_parameter %}` (not `{% add_get_paramater %}`).

Comment: I can't be more stupid than now. Need a coffee. Thanks for pointing out